# {Please Ignore, Syntax Error Found} xlsxwriter formula result is 0 when opened in Excel

Tags: excel, xlsxwriter

I'm using xlsxwriter to create a cell of the average

```
worksheet.write_formula('R7', '=AVERAGE(E3:E303')
```

***"EDIT: Thanks to @BigBen syntax error in  '=AVERAGE(E3:E303') caused the problem!"***

but when I open the .xlsx with Microsoft Excel I get an error
[image]
[image]

**And the cell value is 0.**

I have found similar posts and answers have all been to not use non-excel applications as mentioned in the original statement from McNamara below.

"This is the method recommended in the Excel documentation and in general it works fine with spreadsheet applications. However, **applications that don’t have a facility to calculate formulas** will only display the 0 results. Examples of such applications are Excel Viewer, PDF Converters, and some mobile device applications."

BUT I don't understand why using Microsoft Excel will still give me this '0' problem?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'=AVERAGE(E3:E303)'` - it seems like you're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: That's right... I overlooked this stupid mistake...